# Coinbase Connect (OAuth2) "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed."

Tags: node.js, express, coinbase-api

Dear stackoverflowser,

I'm stying to build an Electron app with Coinbase intergration.

First I'm going to make the server (NodeJS) work with OAuth2.

Every thing works great, but when I want to change the `code` into an `access token` with the instructed post request it gives me the following error:

`{
error: "invalid_request",
error_description: "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed."
}`

I already added `https://localhost:3000/auth/coinbase/callback` and `https://localhost:3000/profile` to the valid API URI's.

I wasn't successful in figuring it out after several hours.

My server is this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs')
var https = require('https');
var coinbase = require('coinbase')
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/coinbase.dev.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/coinbase.dev.crt'),
};

var client_id = 'gues it'
var client_secret = 'gues it'

app.use(express.static('static'));

app.get('/login/coinbase', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('https://www.coinbase.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/auth/coinbase/callback&client_id=' + client_id + '&scope=wallet:user:read,wallet:accounts:read')
})

app.get('/auth/coinbase/callback', function(req, res) {
    var data = {
        client_id: client_id,
        client_secret: client_secret,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        code: req.query.code,
        redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:3000/profile'
    }

    request.post(
        'https://api.coinbase.com/oauth/token', data, function (error, response, body) {
            console.log(body)
            res.send(body)
        }
    );
})

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('home')
})

app.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
    res.send('profile')
})

var server = https.createServer(options, app);

server.listen(3000)
```

Thanks in advance,

Theo

**[EDIT]**
I contacted the Coinbase developers and they were surprised that there was no NodeJS example on OAuth with Coinbase, so they added it to their roadmap.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by one of the following:

1. You do not have `'http://127.0.0.1:3000/profile'` listed as a valid redirect API in your application settings.
2. You are reusing an authorization code that has already been exchanged for a token.
3. This section of [this page](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/security-best-practices):

> ### OAuth2 Redirect URI
>
> For added security, all redirect_uris must use SSL (i.e. begin with
>   https://). URIs without SSL can only be used for development and
>   testing and will not be supported in production.

Contact api@coinbase.com to get that sorted out.

Comment: I did add `https://localhost:3000/auth/coinbase/callback` and `https://localhost:3000/profile` to the valid redirect URI's. And served my local development server from https with ssl. But I'm still getting the same error. I will edit the code in my question.